# Sending push notification using Malcom API

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, malcom

we are sending APNS through Malcom API. There is no trouble for small messages, but when we create a large message the notification is not being received.

is there any limit on message string length?

is there any limit on the value of a specific key?

the documentation doesn't say nothing about length limitations at the moment.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You're right. In theirs documentation don't mention nothing about it. Anyway, if you send a push through malcom.mymalcom.com into your app, you can see a maximum of characteres when you type the message. So, I guess any push request through the API should have the same restriction.

Answer (score 1):

From the Apple Developers guide:

> The maximum size allowed for a notification payload is 256 bytes; Apple Push Notification Service refuses any notification that exceeds this limit.